# How to remove Startup/Configuration tab from Intellij Plugin extending RunConfigurationBase

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am creating a custom IntelliJ plugin (following the [IntelliJ tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/run_configurations.html)) that implements a custom Run Configuration. My plugin will "run" the contents the open file in the editor on a remote server and display the result in IntelliJ (sort of a script playground). I used the IntelliJ GUI Designer to create the form and it shows up in the Edit Run Configuration, however it shows up under 2 tabs (Configuration and Startup/Configuration) .. neither of which I explicitly define, I assume they come from my extending of RunConfigurationBase?.

```
public class RunConfigurationImpl extends RunConfigurationBase {

    public RunConfigurationImpl(Project project, ConfigurationFactory factory, String name) {
        super(project, factory, name);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public SettingsEditor<? extends RunConfiguration> getConfigurationEditor() {
        return new SettingsEditorImpl();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public SettingsEditor<ConfigurationPerRunnerSettings> getRunnerSettingsEditor(ProgramRunner runner) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkConfiguration() throws RuntimeConfigurationException {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public RunProfileState getState(@NotNull Executor executor, @NotNull ExecutionEnvironment executionEnvironment) throws ExecutionException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The first tab is fine (Configuration) ..
[image]

However I do not want to list the same fields again on the Startup/Connection tab, in fact, I'm happy to just do away with this tab -- or really, I don't care which tab I get rid off, I just 
want the fields to show once.

Any pointers on how to get rid of this tab?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is a consolidation of Vassiliy's answer and ensuing comments.*

In order to remove the Startup/Connection tab in the custom Run Configuration UI, ensure that null is being returned from the methods `getRunnerSettingsEditor()` custom the classes that extends `com.intellij.execution.configurations.RunConfiguration` and `com.intellij.execution.runners.ProgramRunner`

By default the API abstract classes return null for these methods, so make sure you are not overriding them.

Answer (score 0):

See `com.intellij.execution.configurations.RunConfiguration#getRunnerSettingsEditor` It returns `null` by default so let it stay `null`, don’t override it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't do the trick. My Startup/Connection tab is still there. I wasn't overriding getRunnerSettingsEditor, to begin with, but I did with it returning null (in case RunConfigurationBase was). I added breakpoints to see my method was being invoked as well.

Comment: OK, what is com.intellij.execution.runners.ProgramRunner#getSettingsEditor in your case? It has to be `null` too.

Comment: Vassiliy - Yes! Thank you! The problem was my ProgramRunnerImpl's getSettingsEditor() was returning an instance of my SettingsEditor. When return null with that, then the tab goes away!  

If you'd like to update your Answer to include returning null for both(?) RunConfiguration and the ProgramRunner's getRunnerSettingsEditor(), i am happy to upvote and mark as the correct answer!